# I am adding logo to center of qrcode but I am getting bad image quality. How to improve quality?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html5-canvas, qr-code

This is my function through which I am adding logo to qr code.

```js
const qrcode = require('qrcode');
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');

//Using canvas I am adding logo to center of image(center_image) and also passing width
async function create(dataForQRcode, center_image, width, cwidth) {
  const canvas = createCanvas(width, width);
  qrcode.toCanvas(canvas, dataForQRcode, {
    errorCorrectionLevel: 'H',
    version: 5,
    margin: 1,
    color: {
      dark: '#000000',
      light: '#ffffff',
    },
  });

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const img = await loadImage(center_image);
  const center = (width - cwidth) / 2;

  //and using drawImage I am adding logo to qr code

  ctx.drawImage(img, center, center, cwidth, cwidth);
  return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
}
```

Here I am calling the function and passing the all arguments.

```js
const QRcode = await create(
    "Hello guys",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/10013232/pexels-photo-10013232.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    140,
    20
);
```

After that I am getting the qrcode with logo at the center but the quality of logo is very bad. I don't know how to improve the quality of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `width` in `qrcode.toCanvas` options.

```
qrcode.toCanvas(canvas, dataForQRcode, {
    errorCorrectionLevel: 'H',
    version: 5,
    margin: 1,
    width: width,
    color: {
        dark: '#000000',
        light: '#ffffff',
    },
});
```